# JMeter: Generate Random Values in bulk API Request (1 HTTP Request)

Tags: api, jmeter

There is a HTTP request which has bulk API's present in the body.

Eg:

```
[{
"externalKey": "1",
"customerDetails": {
    "address": {
        "address": "111 Bourke St",
        "country": "AU",
        "postcode": "3044",
        "state": "Victoria",
        "unitOrBuilding": "1"
    },
    "emailAddress":"loadtest1@gmail.com,
    "phoneNumberInternational": "+61360000001"

},
{
"externalKey": "2",
"customerDetails": {
    "address": {
        "address": "111 Bourke St",
        "country": "AU",
        "postcode": "3044",
        "state": "Victoria",
        "unitOrBuilding": "1"
    },

    "emailAddress":"loadtest2@gmail.com,
    "phoneNumberInternational": "+61360000002"

}]
```

The external key, email address and telephone numbers must be unique in each request.

I have created a code in RunSwift tool to generate the bulk API requests and then aligned the requests in https://jsonlint.com website and then copied/pasted them in Jmeter.

I believe the above approach has lot of manual dependancies. Hence I would like to know if there is a way to automatically populate the values in JMeter and generate random ones every time I submit the HTTP request. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, check out the following [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

- [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - generates a random number in the given range
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - generates a random string from the given characteres

Example use cases:

- For phone: `+${__Random(1111111111,9999999999,)}`
- For email: `${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}@example.com`

Demo:

[image: JMeter Random Demo]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) for more information on JMeter Functions concept:

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to generate the entire body 50 times in 1 request and have unique telephone and email on all the 50 requests. I believe the above approach is useful if the Request has only 1 block of JSON. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Add your data in a CSV file and the use [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md) plugin to go through your data in a random order by checking `Random order`

[image]